# Создание множества View с помощью цикла

Tags: android

Подскажите, что делаю не так? Пытаюсь циклом создать несколько `ImageView`. В итоге, код создает только один (как минимум, виден только один).

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ArrayList<ImageView> awards = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberSteps; i ++ ) {

    awards.add(new ImageView(this));
    awards.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.award28);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = (displayWidth / (i + 1));
    awards.get(i).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout2.addView(awards.get(i));

}
```

Comment: `numberSteps` чем равно?

Comment: Это не так уж и важно. Например, 5.

Answer (score 1):

1) `layoutParams` у вас один и тот же для всех `ImageView` используется.

2) Зачем постоянно get делать, если проще создать `ImageView` и его использовать, а в конце уже в список добавить?

3) `layoutParams.leftMargin = (displayWidth / (i + 1));` что это? У вас для первого элемента отступ слева будет на длину экрана.

```
ArrayList<ImageView> awards = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberSteps; i ++ ) {
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);
    newImage .setImageResource(R.drawable.award28);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = (displayWidth / (i + 1));
    newImage .setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    linearLayout2.addView(newImage );
    awards.add(newImage );
}
```

Comment: 2) мне с этими объектами в последствие работать, так показалось надежнее
3) это я пытался равномерно по экрану раскидать объекты, неудачно, как оказалось